# Search keyword from different files and return the filename

Tags: python

I'm super duper new in using python and I've tried every keywords and attempts on searching to help me figure out my problem. I want to create a program that helps me search a keyword from different txt files in a folder and return the filename (python).

This has been the fruit of my searches:

```
import glob
import os

path = r'<filepath of the folder>'
keyword = "internet" //ex is internet

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):

    f = open(filename)
    if keyword in f:
    print("filename")
```

I tried running and (surprisingly) it run properly but there's nothing printed but I'm quite sure that there's a file with an internet word inside. And since it didn't print any error or anything at all, not sure if I'm even in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the file using `read()`

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    with open(filename) as f:
        if keyword in f.read():
            print("filename")
```

or read each line and print the filename if the "keyword" is found.

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:            
            if keyword in line:
                print("filename")
                break
```